# Reorder column stack in different screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Say in Bootstrap or Foundation,
Is it possible to achieve this layout?

[image]

You see the problem here?
The top column should be at the bottom when in tablet size.
Push/Pull trick isn't applicable here because this is a 
different type of column reordering.

You  have any ideas?

Comment: Use Flex Box Layout Flex item has ordering and best for layouts.

Comment: If your page structure is really weird, and you want to do things like this, you may be interested in http://gridstylesheets.org/, though I wouldn't call it production-ready.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `order` property in CSS with flex-boxes.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties#order

Check browser compatibility here http://caniuse.com/#search=order

Answer (score 1):

With Foundation, you can use the size-push-units, and size-pull-units classes.  For example: .small-push-10, or .large-pull-7, to adjust the positioning by that many columns.  Be aware, you have to also set the opposite on the relevant elements.  So for your example, if each of the boxes is 12 columns wide, then on the green box you'd have the class small-push-24 (the total width of all the elements you want to push past), and on each of the yellow boxes, you'd have small-pull-12 (the width of the element that's pushing past them).

You can read about it in the documentation here under the heading "Source Ordering": http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Comment: If this won't work, then your code would probably appreciate refactoring.

Comment: You sure? There's no .small-push-24 in foundation classes.

Comment: @ronnel-castillo-ocampo It depends on how many columns you have setup.  I use Foundation with 36 columns often.  The docs page I linked to has working examples for the default column setup.

Comment: We used 12 columns. So any other work around for reordering column using foundation with 12 columns?

Comment: @ronnel-castillo-ocampo The technique holds, just the number of columns will vary depending on what you're doing.  The documentation that I linked to covers it all.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I was able to get: see [**example #1**](http://www.bootply.com/Aqvx4h2OCp).

When I want to stack some columns on top of each other - I just give them size 12 (see example #2) and bootstrap knows how to deal with it, unfortunately doesnt seem to work in nested.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment regarding IE8 Support limits you to a few options, I believe:

1.) If your content in these blocks is not dynamic (meaning it will have a consistent height) you can fake this ordering using negative margins. http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/oXGBRe

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .greenTop {margin-top:260px;}
 .yellow1 {margin-top:-360px;}
}
```

2.) If the block represented by the green area is not especially complex, it may be feasible to have it in the page twice and show/hide each one as needed based on media queries.  http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/BNwpEq

```
.greenTop {display:none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .greenTop {display:block;}
  .greenBottom {display:none;}
}
```

(These both require something like respond.js to get IE8 to play nice with media queries: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9)

Answer (score 1):

**Ronnel Castillo Ocampo**, Hi have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au7cLdaL/)** I use Bootstrap and some media query breakpoints to do this with some show and hide etc.
No push/pull either and no negative margin values. Just a simple straight forward way.
Have a look and see if this way flies for you when you resize it.

Here is a large view of the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au7cLdaL/embedded/result/)**.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.space {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}    
.block-gray {
  margin-top: 2%;  
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.block-green-top {
  margin-top: 0%;  
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}     
.block-green {
  margin-top: 2%;  
  height: 100px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
} 
.block-yellow {
  margin-top: 2%;   
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}     
.block-right {
  margin-top: 2%; 
}
.block {
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 400px;
}    
.borders {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
    
@media(max-width:1200px) {
.block-green-top {
  display: none; 
} 
.block-green {
  margin-left: 15px;  
}
.block-yellow {
  margin-left: 15px;  
}    
} 
@media(max-width:320px) {
.block-green {
  margin-left: 0px;  
}
.block-yellow {
  margin-left: 0px;  
}
.col-xs-320 {
  width: 100%;  
} 
.block {
  height: 100px;
}      
}         
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
    
<div class="container">      
    <div class="container col-xs-320 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1 borders block-gray"></div>
    <div class="container col-xs-320 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 hidden-lg text-center block">
        Your content that would fill this area
    </div>        
    <div class="col-xs-320 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 block">
        <div class="col-xs-320 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 borders block-green-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-320 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 borders block-yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-320 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 borders block-yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-320 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 hidden-lg borders block-green"> </div>
    </div>    
</div> 
    
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great - I love it. If it's not too much trouble, would you please walk me thru `<div class="container">` - I don't see how you did it. And what`s `col-xs-320`?

Comment: Hi there, The div with just the class `container` you don't really need this at all. I just used it to wrap the code so it would not expand to the full screen when resized for this demo, it just adds a lot of padding/margin to the sides. Just remove this when you use it in your code.  With the main code, You can see I use `hidden-lg` as well as media breakpoints to control hiding some divs.. the top green div and a large div below the gray div. I created the `col-xs-320` to change the state of all divs at a breakpoint of 320 px.  Does this help. Just ask if you need more explanation here.

Comment: I know that `container` plays the role of a wrapper and has its own margins and paddings etc. At first, I thought your `block-green-top` and `block-green` is the same block and would contain the same info, but later I realized that is not. So no further questions and thank you for the follow up.

Comment: Yes, you just put the same info/text in both green divs and it will show in the right place as where you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it work in Foundation with nesting and the col ordering classes. However, this requires some hidden columns and that the hidden columns must be the same height as the 2 yellow blocks...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 columns gr">
        -
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 large-reset-order medium-6 medium-push-6 small-6 small-push-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns hide-for-large-only hide-for-xlarge-only">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns hide-for-large-only hide-for-xlarge-only">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 medium-push-12 small-12 small-push-12 columns gre">
                green
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-6 medium-pull-12 small-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns ye">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns ye">
                2 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/HmKmY5g5TB